# json can't be displayed as php array

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

The examples I checked seems simple but I can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong.
I'm trying to convert and display JSON text as object array in PHP.

```
$json = '{"color1":red, "color2":blue, "color3":yellow}';
    $arr= json_decode($json, true);
    print_r($arr);
```

It doesn't output anything. but when I print $json, the output is just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that's not json, try

```
$json = '{"color1":"red", "color2":"blue", "color3":"yellow"}';
$arr= json_decode($json, true);
print_r($arr);
```

notice the strings are quoted with `"`, also see http://json.org

Comment: oops, right that's why I was feeling iffy with my json.. I copied the json from a website. thanks